# difference between mtime +0 and mtime 0

Tags: unix, find

I an using mtime with find . I am duing it for first time .
I see a script which moves file from one location to other.

```
 `find . \ -mtime +0 -exec mv {} target \ ;`
```

I want to understand does +0 means only for file created before 24 hrs?
   Now as these files are moved to target i also want to modify there permission to one appropiate for everyone to read. So i used the command

```
 `find target -mtime 0 -exec chmod 644 {} \;`
```

I want to really get hole of difference between usage of +0 , 0 . Does 0 only signified between now and 24 hr while +0 is from 24 and more old ? My main purpose here is to modify the permission of all files in target dir where i have just moved them . As they can be many i jst want to run one command and do it all.

Comment: Quite answered in this answer: [Why does find -mtime +1 only return files older than 2 days?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/174743/40596) --> `find . -mtime +0` finds files modified greater than 24 hours ago. `find . -mtime 0` finds files modified between now and 1 day ago

Answer (score -1):

I recommend that you consult the documentation prior to asking for help. The [man-age](https://manned.org/find.1) for `find` explains numeric test:

```
+n  for greater than n,
-n  for less than n,
 n  for exactly n.
```

and clarifies their interpretation with regard to file timestamp tests `-atime`, `-ctime`, and `-mtime`:

```
-mtime n
   File's  data  was last modified less than, more
   than or exactly n*24 hours ago.  See  the  com-
   ments for -atime to understand how rounding af-
   fects the interpretation of  file  modification
   times.

-atime n
   File  was last accessed less than, more than or
   exactly n*24 hours ago.  When find figures  out
   how  many 24-hour periods ago the file was last
   accessed, any fractional part is ignored, so to
   match  -atime  +1,  a file has to have been ac-
   cessed at least two days ago.
```

As you can see, `+0` means older than 24 hours and `0` within the last 24 hours.

Answer (score -3):

```
   +n     for greater than n days,
   -n     for less than n days,
    n     for exactly n days.
```

+0 - all files older than now , which will be all files in your directory

-0 - all files newer than now , means no files

0 - all files modified now - you will get /root/.bash_history if you are doing it in  /root folder as it gets modified instantly

for 24hrs you can use +1,-1,1

+1 will be all files which are older than 1 day

-1 will be all files which are old up to 1 day

1 will be all files which are exact 1 day old

Comment: This answer is factually wrong. See the documentation and experiment yourself.